# onChange useState one character behind

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, onchange, setstate, async.js

I have a simple search component and I want to build an autocomplete filter, but my onChange event handler is one character behind.

If I type "tsla" into the search bar my value will be "tsl"

```
<TextField
                className={classes.queryField}
                fullWidth
                InputProps={{
                  startAdornment: (
                    <InputAdornment position="start">
                      <SvgIcon fontSize="small" color="action">
                        <SearchIcon />
                      </SvgIcon>
                    </InputAdornment>
                  )
                }}
                onChange={event => {
                  setValue(event.target.value);
                  setAuto(
                    tickers
                      .filter(
                        f =>
                          JSON.stringify(f)
                            .toLowerCase()
                            .indexOf(value) !== -1
                      )
                      .slice(0, 10)
                  );
                  console.log(auto);
                }}
                value={value}
                placeholder="Search for a stock"
                variant="outlined"
              />
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are sill using the old `value` variable when you call setAuto.

```js
const Search = (props) => {
  handleChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value
    setValue(value);
    setAuto(tickers.filter((ticker) => JSON.stringify(ticker).toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1).slice(0, 10));
    console.log(auto);
  };

  return (
    <TextField
      className={classes.queryField}
      fullWidth
      InputProps={{
        startAdornment: (
          <InputAdornment position="start">
            <SvgIcon fontSize="small" color="action">
              <SearchIcon />
            </SvgIcon>
          </InputAdornment>
        ),
      }}
      onChange={handleChange}
      placeholder="Search for a stock"
      value={value}
      variant="outlined"
    />
  );
};
```

The solution is to pass the new value object to both setValue and to setAuto.

```js
  handleChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value
    setValue(value);
    setAuto(tickers.filter((ticker) => JSON.stringify(ticker).toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1).slice(0, 10));
    console.log(auto);
  };
```